# zookeeper ruby client keeps disconnecting

Tags: ruby, apache-zookeeper

I am playing with the zk client (https://github.com/zk-ruby/zk)
but when I create the client and perform the get operation I see every now and then the connection is lost:

```
[3] pry(main)> zk = ZK::Client::Threaded.new('localhost:2181')
=> #<ZK::Client::Threaded:70121951431300 zk_session_id=0x1440e09ba110007 ...>
[4] pry(main)> zk.get("/")
=> ["",
 #<Zookeeper::Stat:0x007f8d151ed1c0
... ]
[5] pry(main)> zk.get("/")
Zookeeper::Exceptions::NotConnected: the connection is shutting down
from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/zookeeper-                  1.4.8/lib/zookeeper/continuation.rb:124:in `block in value'
```

Can someone point me to some guide where I can learn about the connection management semantics?